# A mix of complex analysis questions.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a mix of complex analysis questions I can't split into other questions because they are quite trivial.

In [this discussion of Runge's theorem](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/runge.pdf), it says:

> Polynomials are holomorphic, and hence any sequence of polynomials which
>   converges uniformly on an open set converges to a holomorphic function on that set. This follows from Morera’s theorem.

My intuition tells me this is correct, but why does that follow from Morera's theorem which loosely states loop integral equaling $0$ imply $f$ is analytic.

Also, what is the curve $z = e^{2\pi i t}$ in the complex plane $(t \in [0,1])$? I don't think it's a circle because circles are of the form $z = re^{it} + c$.

Also (this may be self-answered after the above is answered), what do they mean by "has a hole"

> The problem is that $f$does not extend to a holomorphic function inside
>   $\gamma$ , and this is possible because $K$ as a “hole”.

I under the first part because $\gamma$ presumably encloses $0$.

EDIT: OKay understand the "hole part" now. Basically a little part of the circle overlaps with $K$.

Comment: Regarding the question about whether the curve is a circle: the statement is correct. There are many parameterizations of a circle. Yours requires $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @MPW, oh right, $u = \frac{1}{2\pi i}$.

Comment: Not sure what your response means. My point is that in both cases, the exponent ranges from $0$ to $2\pi i$ through pure imaginary values.

Comment: I just mean I gave the reparametrization of the usual one I was thinking of.

Comment: It isn't quite right, but I think I know what you're driving at.

Comment: I forgot the $t$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one about polynomials, take any closed line integral in $U$ of each $f_n$ (polynomials) and you get $0$. Exchange the limit by uniform continuity and you see that any closed line integral is $0$ for $f$ so by Morera it must be holomorphic. Let $C$ be any closed curve in $U$, then

$$\int_C f=\int_C \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_C f_n = 0$$

where the last equality holds because the closed integrals of the $f_n$ are $0$ due to the $f_n$ being holomorphic, and actually the same argument shows that the uniform convergence of any holomorphic functions converges to a holomorphic function.

Also, in terms of "hole" this has a very technical definition involving homotopy classes of closed curves, so I would look at the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy

Comment: Exchange limits? Don't you take only one limit?

Comment: Yes only one limit, I think its a habit to say "exchange limits" for some reason.

Comment: Oh that's what you meant by "exchange".

Comment: I thought for "hole" they mean the little part of the circle that eats out the $K$

Comment: Put very simply in this specific example, a "hole" just means that the function behaves very poorly very close to this point. But everywhere else it is fine. $\frac 1 z$ behaves very nicely away from 0, but there is no value we could assign $\frac 1 z$ in order for our new function to be "nice" (holomorphic) everywhere in $\mathbb C$

Comment: But the pdf says this "hole" is in $K$, he isn't referring to $0$.

Comment: Yes, this is because $K$ is not simply connected and inside its "hole" is the singularity of $\frac 1 z$. I'm trying to simplify the subject for you but its not something you can just sum up in one sentence.

Comment: I thought $K$ was an infinite rectangle, that is not simply connected?

Comment: It's a typo it should be $K = \{z\in \mathbb C | \frac 1 2 \leq |z|\leq 2\}$, you are correct in thinking that an infinite rectangle would be simply connected but $K$ is an annulus.

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't caught that either.

Comment: I actually don't understand the purpose of the example now…but I think I have to ask that in a different question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22652/discussion-between-matthew-levy-and-hawk).

Comment: Having some problems getting into chat…just a sec.

Comment: sigh, each time i click on chat it says I am not logged in….this will take a while for me to figure out